# javascript getelementbyid ... how to 'get' the "html" variable

Tags: javascript, accessibility, web-standards, getelementbyid

```
function allowscroll()
{
if (screen.width<1200){document.getElementById('html').style.cssText='overflow-x: scroll !important;';};
}

<body onLoad="allowscroll();">
```

hi there, the above code works for any element, e.g. subbing "html" for "wrapper", but how is it possible to edit the css applied to html? Basically, because of overflow:hidden not inheriting in ie7 - which causes a big empty righthand margin and horizontal scrollbar (only in ie7, ie 8 compatibilty), ive set the css to

```
html {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

this is the only way to fix it without losing necessary functionality, e.g. overflowed graphics visibilty.

and this is all well and good, however, lower screen resolutions need the horizontal scroll just to see all of the page itself, so I'm attempting to restore the horizontal scrollbar for those users - and restore the big right margin for anyone who happens to be, for example ie7 1024 by 768 - I can live with that (unless anyone happens to have a superdupa solution).

```
document.getElementById('html').style.cssText='overflow-x: scroll !important;';
```

So the above code works for editing the CSS of any element, but not the CSS of the html.

I've also tried:

```
function allowscroll()
{
if (screen.width<1200){document.getElementByName('html').style.cssText='overflow-x: scroll !important;';};
}
```

and

```
function allowscroll()
{
if (screen.width<1200){window.style.cssText='overflow-x: scroll !important;';};
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, - if it helps in seeing the solution, the link where this applies is: [delight design](http://www.delightwebdesign.co.uk), basically, its how to take out:

```
html {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

from the css when in lower screen resolutions...

many thanks

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to get the `html` element:

```
document.documentElement
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
document.body.parentNode
```

But in all honesty, there must be a better way. I don't have time right now to track down what exactly happened here, but [from what I can tell](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/), adding `position:relative` to whatever needs the overflow might help.

Comment: thats awesome!! I've never learnt so much from asking a question, if you wish, let me know your paypal email - I'd happily "buy you a pint" so to speak. thanks and cheers

Comment: @Will: Stop changing the "Accepted" answer while soliciting people's email address/paypal information. If there was an answer that was helpful, select it. Do not attempt financial transactions here.

Comment: I tried each and found a better answer each time and learnt as I went, truely sorry if I've offended sensibilities or protocol, I merely wanted to express genuine gratitude.

Comment: @Will I actually don't have a PayPal account. All I ask is that when your friends and loved ones seek genius, creativity, and an unflappable will to succeed, you whisper a single word: "sdleihssirhc."

Comment: perhaps ive lived too much in a something for something reality - there are people in the world (myself included) who help others for the joy of helping. in some respects this is a step toward restoring my faith in others, altruistic strangers lending a helping hand even if like passing ships in the night..

Comment: but patrick, i honestly wasnt 'attempting' anything, not an attempt but an offer of thanks, an offer which stands (if you wish get in touch) and with or without that, heres a written thanks, because i spent hours today which you guys helped in leaps and bounds, and then 1 "position: relative;" did it, but then ive learnt those other things (document.documentElement) too which will help another time, everything helps and its all good. im appreciative thats all, thanks again, best wishes, Will

Answer (score 2):

Try `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]`

Note I just edited the answer as getElementsByTagName returns an array.  You want the first element in that array.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement):

```
document.documentElement
```

It has [full browser suport](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t124).

Comment: @Will: What's not happening? Are you saying it isn't selecting the `<html>` document element, or are you saying that your CSS doesn't do what you want?

Comment: for the record, when i said it wasnt happening, at that point i was trying document.documentElement("html")[0].style.cssText='overflow-x: scroll !important;'; ....smiles... you see whats simple for one person can be a world away for someone else, but i'm learning!, cheers and thanks